# How to go back after accidentally hitting H in visual mode?

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions

While selecting in visual mode I often accidentally hit <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>L</kbd> instead of <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> due to having used <kbd>Shift</kbd> for some previous command (like e.g. <kbd>V</kbd> to start selection by line) and not yet released it when trying to move (because hands are not in ideal synchronization).

In normal mode this is not a problem, because a remedy is quick: just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and continue. But in visual mode this "go back" command doesn't appear to work. Currently I have to go to normal mode and start selecting all over again, which is an unproductive fix.

So, how can I go back in visual mode? Is there another mapping for this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [``` `` ```](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%60%60) motion, which goes back to the position before the last jump.

If you only care about the line, not the column (for example, if you're using visual line mode), then `''` also works.